# Ignore escaped double quote characters swift

Tags: regex, swift, escaping, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

I am trying to validate a phone number using `NSPredicate` and regex. The only problem is when setting the regex Swift thinks that I am trying to escape part of it due to the backslashes. How can I get around this?

My code is as follows:

```
let phoneRegEx = "^((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Swift **regular string literals**, you need to double-escape the slashes to define *literal* backslashes:

```swift
let phoneRegEx = "^((\\(?0\\d{4}\\)?\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3})|(\\(?0\\d{3}\\)?\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{4})|(\\(?0\\d{2}\\)?\\s‌​?\\d{4}\\s?\\d{4}))(\\s?#(\\d{4}|\\d{3}))?$"
```

[Starting from Swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166678/raw-strings-in-swift), you can use **raw string literals** and escape regex escapes with a single backslash:

```swift
let phoneRegEx = #"^((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s‌?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$"#
```

Please refer to the *Regular Expression Metacharacters* table on the [**ICU Regular Expressions**](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) page to see what regex escapes should be escaped this way.

Please mind the difference between the regex escapes (in the above table) and *string literal escape sequences* used in the *regular string literals* that you may check, say, at [**Special Characters in String Literals**](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID295):

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters `\0` (null character), `\\` (backslash), `\t` (horizontal tab), `\n` (line feed), `\r` (carriage return), `\"` (double quotation mark) and `\'` (single quotation mark)
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar value, written as `\u{n}`, where `n` is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number ([Unicode](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID293) is discussed in Unicode below)

So, in *regular string literals*, `"\""` is a `"` string written as a string literal, and you do not have to escape a double quotation mark for the regex engine, so `"\""` string literal regex pattern is enough to match a `"` char in a string. However, `"\\\""`, a string literal repesenting `\"` literal string will also match `"` char, although you can already see how redundant this regex pattern is. Also, `"\n"` (an LF symbol) matches a newline in the same way as `"\\n"` does, as `"\n"` is a literal representation of the newline char and `"\\n"` is a regex escape defined in the ICU regex escape table.

In raw string literals, `\` is just a literal backslash.